# SQL derived column call number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query as below:

```
 SELECT  top  8  (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top8HotFilms,
  Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) as DayOfCount,
  count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence 
  FROM [MOVIES].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory]
  where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= 
                (SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) 
  GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName , 
           Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) 
  ORDER BY filmoccurence desc
```

The result are as below:

```
Movies           Session Day    Occurence .tix
*SAN ANDREAS        20150531    2156
*MASSS              20150531    1954
*TOMORROWLAND       20150531    990
SPY                 20150531    825
PITCH PERFECT 2     20150531    374
MAD MAX FURY ROAD   20150531    302
*MASSS              20150601    268
*SAN ANDREAS        20150601    257
```

Qns now, how to I derive a column called number, end result as below?

```
Number Movies            Session Day    Occurence .tix
   1  *SAN ANDREAS          20150531    2156
   2  *MASSS                20150531    1954
   3  *TOMORROWLAND         20150531    990
   4  SPY                   20150531    825
   5  PITCH PERFECT 2       20150531    374
   6  MAD MAX FURY ROAD     20150531    302
   7  *MASSS                20150601    268
   8  *SAN ANDREAS          20150601    257
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try below

```
SELECT  top  8 RANK() 
            OVER (ORDER BY count( OrderTH_strMovieName) desc) AS Number, 
      (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top8HotFilms,
      Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) as DayOfCount,
      count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence 
      FROM [MOVIES].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory]
      where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= 
                    (SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) 
      GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName , 
               Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112)
```

Eg:

```
    create table test
(name varchar(10),
 age numeric)

 insert into test values ('John',10);
 insert into test values('Happy',20);
 insert into test values ('mary',35);
  insert into test values ('mary',35);
 insert into test values ('John',10);

SELECT  top  2 ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY sum(age)) as number,
     name as n,
     sum(age) as age_sum
```

from test
   group by name
 Order by name

```
   number   n   age_sum
   1     Happy   20
  2      John   20
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'filmoccurence'.

Comment: @EugeneJONG oh it is because you are ordering it by desc

Comment: What should be the right query then if I want above result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79249/discussion-between-sachu-and-eugene-jong).

Answer (score 0):

Select ROW NUMBER over your query:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
  select top 8 RANK() OVER(ORDER BY moviesHit.filmoccurence ASC) as Rank,
  moviesHit.Top8HotFilms,moviesHit.filmoccurence
  from 
  (
   SELECT (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top8HotFilms,

   count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence 
   FROM [MOVIES].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory] 
   where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= 
     (SELECT     DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) 
   GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName  
   ) as moviesHit    order by moviesHit.filmoccurence ASC
```

Comment: I removed order by from the view and put it outside

Comment: 1 *ALOHA 20150607 2
1 *ENTOURAGE 20150606 2
1 *SPY 20150601 2
1 *3D JURASSIC WORLD 20150612 2
1 *TOMORROWLAND 20150603 2
1 PITCH PERFECT 2 20150603 2
1 *GOOD KILL 20150603 2
1 *SAN ANDREAS 20150605 2

Comment: When you do a group by you have to put outside anything other than the row refrence . What is a day of count ?